# Horizontal UItableView ios 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

I would like to implement an iPhone application based on `ios7`  and I  need some help to create horizontal `UItableView`.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use a table view use a [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

You don't need a grid, just a single row will do, and it will behave like a tableview but horizontally.

A general question, so a general answer.

Comment: a great suggestion! Switch of flow layout direction to horizontal is all that is needed